# Stop event bubbling after initial focus events within an live area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down menu that I would like users to be able to tab through. I have the functionality at a fairly good place, once the user tabs into the element the menu slides down, and when the user tabs out it slides up. The only problem is that the focus: is being hit every time the user tabs to a new link in the menu. So the experience is rather... bouncy.

How would I prevent event bubbling until the user tabs out of the live area? Thanks!

```
$('#block-pagestyle-form')
  .live({
    focus:function (){
            $('#pagestyle_current_list').slideDown(250)
    },
    blur: function (){
            $('#pagestyle_current_list').slideUp(250)
    }
  });
```

Edit: 
Sorry about that! The html that I'm tackling is:

```
<div id="block-pagestyle-form">
  <h1><a href="">Menu Title</a></h1>
  <ul id="pagestyle_current_list">
    <li><a href="">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The user needs to be able to tab onto the h1 tag, triggering the .slideDown, and when they tab out of the div, the menu needs to slide up. The code, as it sits now, runs .slideDown() every time an anchor in the menu is tabbed to.

Comment: I am having a tough time figuring out what you are trying to say.  Can you post your code in jsfiddle.net and link us?

Comment: We need example code, we aren't wizards

Comment: Sorry! That was my bad, I've included the code.

Comment: Can you post your CSS?  Here is a link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vHtq7/

Comment: Thanks! I just hid the list. You can test out the behaviour by tabbing into the results pane and going through the list. (Chrome supports tabbed browsing nicely) http://jsfiddle.net/vHtq7/2/

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'm guessing that "#block-pagestyle-form" is contained within each tab, so the focus/blur event listener you're specifying is being added to each tab, when really you want the same event for all of the tabs.</s>

Try attaching the focus/blur events to an element that contains all of the tabs.  I don't use jquery that much, so I'm just guessing here...

```
$('#parent-element-which-contains-all-tabs')
  .live({
    focus:function (){
            $('#pagestyle_current_list').slideDown(250)
    },
    blur: function (){
            $('#pagestyle_current_list').slideUp(250)
    }
  });
```

Comment: @Erin, if you think Dave's answer solves your question feel free to accept it by clicking the outline of a CheckBox in the top left of his answer.

Comment: @Abe, No, it doesn't solve my question. I was just mentioning that his description was correct.
@Dave, The issue is that the focus is still fired each and every time an <a> gets tabbed to, so when you tab through a menu of four items it runs the slideDown animation four times. Do you know of a way that I could only fire the focus animation on the initial tab in?

Comment: I gave JS fiddle a try and I see that the solution I mentioned didn't work.  I read a little bit about JQuery's live, delegate, and bind functions but wasn't able to come up with a working solution.  I'll post back if I get some time to look at it; but for now I'm going to strikethrough my answer b/c it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for taking a look at it. It's a real doozy of a problem and I'm absolutely stumped. I'll check out those functions and see if there is anything that I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but you can stop any previous animations by using the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method:

```
$('#block-pagestyle-form')
  .live({
    focus:function (){
            $('#pagestyle_current_list').stop(true, true).slideDown(250)
    },
    blur: function (){
            $('#pagestyle_current_list').slideUp(250)
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think the issue is that focus: is being called every time they hit an anchor tag. I tried the stop(), but it doesn't appear to be fixing this behaviour.